# ReactStrap: Problem with LONG dropdown menu that's displayed inside of a table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have this dropDown menu that's rendered inside of a table:
[image]

It's a long dropdown list containing 16 items. So when I click on it and try to scroll down, to reach the last items, this happens:

[image]

The whole table scrolls down, and the drop down list gets dragged along. So when I try to reach the last items, I couldn't. And the whole table UI gets messed-up.

This is the dropdown list code:

```
const statusDropDown = (
      <Dropdown
        isOpen={this.state.statusUpdateDropDownOpen}
        toggle={this.toggleStatusUpdateDropDown}
        // scrollable={true}
      >
        <DropdownToggle className="my-dropdown" caret>
          {this.state.statusUpdateDropDownValue}
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          {Object.entries(listeDesStatus).map(([key, value], i) => {
            console.log("INSIDE TABLE, value is");
            console.log(value);
            return (
              <DropdownItem
                key={i}>
                <div value={key} onClick={this.changeStatusUpdateDropDownValue}>
                  {value}
                </div>
              </DropdownItem>
            );
          })}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    );
```

And this is where it's rendered:

```
 <tbody>
{Object.entries(this.state.operationSavInformation).map(
  ([key, value]) =>
    key !== "id" &&
    (key === "Status" ? (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>{key}</td>
        <td>
          {statusDropDown}
        </td>
      </tr>
    ) : (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>{key}</td>
        <td>
          <strong>{value}</strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))
)}
</tbody>
```

I have made some research and found-out that fixing the height might solve this problem:

```
 const statusDropDown = (
  <Dropdown
    isOpen={this.state.statusUpdateDropDownOpen}
    toggle={this.toggleStatusUpdateDropDown}
    // scrollable={true}
  >
    <DropdownToggle className="my-dropdown" caret>
      {this.state.statusUpdateDropDownValue}
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu style={{ maxHeight: "28px" }}>
      {Object.entries(listeDesStatus).map(([key, value], i) => {
        console.log("INSIDE TABLE, value is");
        console.log(value);
        return (
          <DropdownItem
            key={i}>
            <div value={key} onClick={this.changeStatusUpdateDropDownValue}>
              {value}
            </div>
          </DropdownItem>
        );
      })}
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Although this kind of solves the problem (I can access the last items), this has caused a side effect with the first element for some reason.
Besides, what I actually wanted is to make the height of the drop-down list fix AND make it scrollable. For example: Showing two items and to see the rest the user can scroll down inside the dropdown list.
Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the dropdown a `max-height` and `overflow: scroll`.

```css
.really-long-list {
  background: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="really-long-list">
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style={{ maxHeight: "28px", overflow:"scroll"}} in your DropdownMenu.